# What is the name of the given formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Could anyone say what is the name of the given formula?

[image]

Comment: I guess:  "$y$ is a polynomial in $x$"

Comment: $y {}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the general formula for a polynomial in $x$, as said by GEdgar. I will elaborate a little further.

This equation is for a polynomial of the $nth$ degree. For example, when $n=2$, you have $y=a_0x^2+a_1x+a_2x^0$, the familiar parabola. When $n=3$, a cubic and so on.

The $a_n$ is the coefficients of the polynomial. For example, one may define $a_n$ as the natural numbers. Then, a polynomial of degree $4$ would look like $y=x^4+2x^3+3x^2+4x+5$.